# Page not found SEO

Tags: 7

Drupal offers us the possibility to set the 404 page displayed for the end users (this can be set in the admin configuration).

Ex : If you type

http://www.example.com/doesntexist

you are redirected to

http://www.example.com/my-custom-404-page (alias for a node)

While this is a good approach for end users, what about the side effects for the `Google bot` ?

Generally speaking, if the Google Bot received a 404 error for a page, it will stop crawling it.

However, with the solution displayed above, the headers of the response page are :

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found

So my question is : is there any way to have the 404 HTTP code while having a nice custom error page ?

Comment: Sadly true:( bot indexing that page. You can replace http header in a hook, eg. hook_node_view_alter(), `if ($build['#node']->nid == your custom 404 page node ID) {`, then `drupal_add_http_header('HTTP/1.0', '404 Not Found');`

Comment: I also like your hook idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing [Custom Error](http://drupal.org/project/customerror) will fix this problem.

I am using this module and I've set up custom 403 and 404 page for my site. Example: http://www.nemo-project.org/board/doesntexist - and it returns 404 according to http://www.seoconsultants.com/tools/headers

(I am not sure if this module is *necessary* to get the correct HTTP response codes, but it is a nifty module and does the job - I use it on all my Drupal 7 sites.)

Comment: Do you use it for Drupal 7 ?

Comment: No that obviously to me since I only worked with Drupal 7 :) Can't say what D6 looks like.